# Jquery Selectable, disabling multiselect by dragging mouse

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

I want to disable the multiselect option on mouse drag event, user can select multiple one by one holding control key though. The problem is, I am sending an ajax service call in select event, and if I select a considerable number of large options, it skips some. In debugging mode, it runs fine when i let each call being sent upon breakpoint though.

Comment: So you want to stop multiple items being selected using ctrl + mouse ?

Comment: click on any item and try to drag it, the mouse will create a rectangle of the area you select http://jqueryui.com/selectable/

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-multiple-select-for-jquery-selectable-ui . They explain why this is illogical. Please provide your code so we can fix the ajax service call.

Comment: yeah, it seems illogical to use the selectable if I dont use multiselect by mouse. In fact, i just coded custom js to handle multiselect. Actually, i am utilizing a rest service with jquery, and for multiselect or unselecting many items at once, it fires the events fine one by one, I can catch them in debugger too, but when I let them being fired continuously, the service is called for only some selected items, randomly.

Comment: I may be wrong, actually, I am working on Custom Server Control, so after each service call, I partial post back the page by clicking a button by jquery, i guess the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've so far found is to hack the code! The current source code is here:  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/selectable.js

You need to basically strip out `_mouseDrag` completely, but leave `_mouseStart` and `_mouseStop`. Less invasive would be to add a special option for it, and if your flag is set then return at the very top of `_mouseDrag`.

---

BTW, my use case is simpler than yours: drag to multiple select is not only not needed, but actually gets in the way. By "get in the way" I mean if you ctrl-click to select an item, then ctrl-click to unselect it works. But, if while ctrl-click to unselect you drag the mouse (just slightly) the mouseDrag event takes over, so the ctrl button gets ignored, and it gets selected again (i.e. the unselect fails). That is the techie explanation, what the users say is: sometimes ctrl-click to unselect doesn't work.